# Question of the Week #44

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post #44 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any questions that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake. We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From last week via @Sathya:

[How much information can websites get about your browser/PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/470348/how-much-information-can-websites-get-about-your-browser-pc)

> Does anyone know of any other sites that will be able to get more information from the user passively like this? I'm not talking about port-sniffing or any kind of interaction from the user, just the info that a server can get from a 'dumb' visit.

Comment: Specifically it can request the browser and version. It can also usually get the monitor resolution info. These are transmitted so the site can change to provide you the best experience. I should be able to also get your IP address so it should be able to geographically (roughly) locate you. If it blips a SSL type connection request, it should also be able to get what encryption you support. I remember there were MANY other things it can request. There used to be sites that you could go to that would spit back all the info it could get on you based on a single connection, but I can't remember

Comment: It can also get basic OS info as I recall.

Comment: @Blackbeagle: And I believe the website you were after is http://browserspy.dk/